# How to create a infinite loop with an n-tuple cycle in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

This's a simple loop:

```
var i=0;
while(i<4){
    console.log(i);
    i++;
};
```

This loop show 1~3 on your debugger console. Now, How i do same thing but with infinite cycle(0~3)? Like this:
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
...

Comment: Doing this with anykind of loop, no delay and without abort condition would cause the browser to hang. So what do you need this for?

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a little bit of abstraction, you can use a closure and hide the logic there. Example:

```
function generator(valueCb) {
  return function() {
    var i = 0;

    return {
      next: function() {
        var ret = valueCb(i);
        i++;

        return ret;
      }
    };
  }();
}

function cycle() {
  var items = arguments;

  return generator(function(i) {
    return items[i % items.length];
  });
}

var nums = cycle(0, 1, 2, 3);

console.log(nums.next()); // 0
console.log(nums.next()); // 1
console.log(nums.next()); // 2
console.log(nums.next()); // 3
console.log(nums.next()); // 0
```

Just call `next` as many times as you like. I have [discussed this approach in more detail at my blog](http://www.nixtu.info/2012/03/implementing-generators-in-javascript.html).

Comment: Seems to be really nice approach. +1 :)

Comment: The cool thing is that the items you pass to `cycle` are arbitrary. Thankfully we'll get real generators with ES6 so we can drop little hacks like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function inf( n, m ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        for ( var j = 0; j < m; j++ ) {
            console.log(j);
        }
    }
}

inf(5,4);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ddjr6/)

First identifier `n` is how many times you want to output the same result based on identifier `m`, which is actually the numbers, in your case `0 1 2 3`

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo operator:

```
var i=0;
while(1){
    console.log(i % 4);
    i++;
}
```

(This will overflow eventually, but I guess you can fix that.)